# R - Return first value of row in df based on first occurence of column value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df of 6 columns:

```
      Time               A_1               A_2               A_3      mean      SEM
1 3.474000          0.000000          42.22222          46.29630  0.000000 0.000000
2 3.538333          0.000000          42.22222          46.29630  0.000000 0.000000
3 3.602667          0.000000          42.22222          50.00000  0.000000 0.000000
4 3.667000          3.030303          50.02156          51.85185  1.010101 1.010101
5 3.731333          3.030303          52.38745          77.77778  1.010101 1.010101
6 3.795667          3.030303          48.25852          77.77778  1.010101 1.010101
```

I want to check columns A_1, A_2 and A_3 independently for the first value greater than 49.9999, and for that row, return the value in the Time column.

I can get the row index for each column using `rowA1<-which.max(df$A_1 >49.9999)`, but I'm not sure how to get from the row index to the Time column value for that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution with `apply()`. First identify the variables with pattern `A_` then you can combine `min()` and `which()` in order to extract that row with time following the mentioned condition. Here the code:

```
#Code
#Index for columns
index <- which(grepl('A_',names(df)))
#Apply
res <- apply(df[,index],2,function(x) df$Time[min(which(x>49.9999))])
```

Output:

```
res
     A_1      A_2      A_3 
      NA 3.667000 3.602667
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Time = c(3.474, 3.538333, 3.602667, 3.667, 3.731333, 
3.795667), A_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 3.030303, 3.030303, 3.030303), A_2 = c(42.22222, 
42.22222, 42.22222, 50.02156, 52.38745, 48.25852), A_3 = c(46.2963, 
46.2963, 50, 51.85185, 77.77778, 77.77778), mean = c(0, 0, 0, 
1.010101, 1.010101, 1.010101), SEM = c(0, 0, 0, 1.010101, 1.010101, 
1.010101)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: The use of `min()` will cause a warning message. Replacing `min(which(x>49.9999))` with `which(x>49.9999)[1]` will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, we can use `summarise` + `across` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% summarise(across(starts_with('A'), ~Time[which(. > 49.99)[1]]))

#  A_1   A_2      A_3
#1  NA 3.667 3.602667
```

Comment: Tried it and it threw an error: `Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.` but I need to improve my dplyr skills so I'll play with it. Thanks for taking the time to get me on the path!

Comment: @AlbertQuackstein I think you also have `plyr` loaded. Try using with `dplyr::summarise`.

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` option with `sapply`

```
sapply(df[startsWith(names(df), 'A')], function(x) df$Time[x > 49.999][1])
# A_1      A_2      A_3 
#  NA 3.667000 3.602667
```